# Need to construct a manual gradient legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to manually construct a gradient legend in ggplot2.  I have a base layer that maps the relationship between days and assaults.  I then add in points from a variety of different dataframes corresponding to weather conditions.

Here is the code for the plot:

```
ggplot(year_2001_2003, aes(wkd_ind, assaults)) + geom_line( ) +
    geom_point(data=top_wmaxc, size = 4, aes(color="yellow")) +
    geom_point(data=top_wmaxb, size = 4, aes(color="orange")) + 
    geom_point(data=top_wmaxa, size = 4, aes(color="red")) +

    geom_point(data=top_wminc, size = 4, aes(color="darkblue")) +
    geom_point(data=top_wminb, size = 4, aes(color="blue")) + 
    geom_point(data=top_wmina, size = 4, aes(color="lightblue")) +

    facet_grid(.~year, scale="free")
```

I now want to construct a legend that moves through my color selection as a gradient from yellow --> light blue.

I thought I could do this with something like:

```
scale_color_gradientn(name="Temperature", 
                      colours = c("yellow", "orange", "red", "darkblue", "blue", "lightblue"),
                      values=c(1.0,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.2,0))
```

But I'm getting an error:
`Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

1) Any thoughts on how to resolve this?
2) None of the colors are corresponding to the named colors I selected.  "lightblue", for example, looks like a green.

To respond to the comment-- here is the head of the df
[image]

All of the dataframes that are constructed like `top_wmaxc` are just top 90 pecentiles for various variables:

```
top_wmaxc <- year_2001_2003[year_2001_2003$w_maxc > quantile(year_2001_2003$w_maxc, 0.90), ]
  top_wmaxc <- year_2001_2003[year_2001_2003$w_maxc > quantile(year_2001_2003$w_maxc, 0.90), ]
  top_wmaxb <- year_2001_2003[year_2001_2003$w_maxb > quantile(year_2001_2003$w_maxb, 0.90), ]
  top_wmaxa <- year_2001_2003[year_2001_2003$w_maxa > quantile(year_2001_2003$w_maxa, 0.90), ]

  top_wminc <- year_2001_2003[year_2001_2003$w_minc > quantile(year_2001_2003$w_minc, 0.90), ]
  top_wminb <- year_2001_2003[year_2001_2003$w_minb > quantile(year_2001_2003$w_minb, 0.90), ]
  top_wmina <- year_2001_2003[year_2001_2003$w_mina > quantile(year_2001_2003$w_mina, 0.90), ]
```

Comment: Please show part of your data `year_2001_2003`. head(year_2001_2003). What's `top_wmaxc`? You grammar is not right. geom_point() should not include the `data` part. You should use scale_color_manual to specify the color.

Comment: Try geom_point(data=top_wmaxc, size = 4, color="yellow"). This would use the color you specified. But would not have a legend.

Comment: ^^ I know that; but my question is about the legend.

Comment: top_wmaxc$col <- "yellow" Then df.new <- do.call(rbind, list(top_wmaxc, top_wmaxb, top_wmaxa, top_wminc, top_wminb, top_wmina)); ggplot(year_2001_2003, aes(wkd_ind, assaults)) + geom_line( ) + geom_point(data=df.new, size = 4, aes(color="col"))

Comment: Thanks for that; i'm not even sure how it works.  I can't see in  "df.new" any of the things that you rbinded.  But it doesn't solve my problem.  I want the some of the dots hues of blue and some of the dots hues of red.  How do I do a gradient?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You specified the color of all the point. It should be discrete now. How does gradient comes out? Can you show a minimum reproducible example.